# how to preserve scroll position in tinyscrollbar

Tags: scroll, scrolltop, tinyscrollbar

Using the tinyscrollbar jquery plugin combined with jquery overlay.  I'd like to preserve the scroll position inside the scrollable container so that when I close the overlay, I return to the scroll position.  Any thoughts on how to do this since using any number of container names, or the window's scrolltop attribute doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered how to do this.

In my situation, I have a grid of images that, when clicked, invoke a jquery overlay.  In the onBeforeLoad section of the overlay function, I use the code below to populate a globally declared variable scrollposition with the current position:

```
scrollposition = Math.abs($('.overview').position().top);
```

Note that I take the absolute value of this position since tinyscrollbar uses a negative offset from the top to move the overview up and out of sight.

Then, in the onBeforeClose of the overlay function, I invoked the tinyscrollbar_update method's ability to set the position of the scrollable area by feeding it scrollposition:

```
$('#scrollbar').tinyscrollbar_update(scrollposition);
```

That's it!

Comment: I'd suggest doing $('#yourscrollbar').find('.overview').position().top since you may have multiple scrollbars and this wouldn't work in that case.